# Elementos repetidos en hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Hola estoy acabando una pequeña aplicación que almacena, el total de ventas de cada empleado dependiendo del producto vendido. Estoy usando para esto un hashMap ya que he pensado que esta estructura de datos es la más eficiente para mi proyecto. El problema lo tengo en que me muestra datos duplicados y no encuentro la manera de quitar estos duplicados, adjunto fuente:

```
public static String totalizarIDEmpleadoArticulo() throws SQLException{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ventas inner join articulos on ventas.idArt = articulos.idArt"
                + " ORDER BY ventas.idEmp, ventas.idArt";

    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    int empleado = 0;
    int articulo;

    String cadena = "";
    double suma = 0;
    rs.beforeFirst();
    Object[] contenido = new String[50];

    boolean correcto = rs.next();
    while (correcto) {
        suma = 0;

        empleado = rs.getInt("idEmp");
        articulo = rs.getInt("idArt");

        while (correcto && empleado == rs.getInt("idEmp")) {
            suma += rs.getDouble("ppu") * rs.getInt("unidades");
            correcto = rs.next();
        }

        contenedor.put(empleado, suma);

        contenido = contenedor.keySet().toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < contenido.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Empleado: " + "\t" + "total vendido:" + "\n" + "----------" + "\t" + "----------"
                        + "\n" + empleado + "\t" + "\t" + suma);

        } 
    }

    return cadena;
}
```

Comment: la repetición es en el sql o en el hashmap?

Comment: Hola lo primero gracias por responder tan rápido @aloMalbarez las repeticiones se me producen en hacer un sout del hashmap

Comment: ahi hay una respuesta que puede darte pistas, segun como quieras los datos de la DB y la estructura de las tablas , o aplicas un distinct o un group

Comment: dudo que los datos hayan estado repetidos en el hashmap, yo creo que simplemente estabas imprimiendo *los mismos datos* varias veces. En cada ciclo del `while(correcto)` imprimes el ultimo empleado `N` veces, donde `N` es la cantidad de empleados agregados hasta ese punto en el hashmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé por qué no te funciona el código como lo tienes, pero lo podrías resolver todo en la consulta SQL.

Esta consulta acumula por `idEmp` e `idArt`, sumando el producto de `ppu` por `unidades`:

```
SELECT ventas.idEmp, ventas.idArt, sum(ppu * unidades) as suma
FROM ventas inner join articulos on ventas.idArt = articulos.idArt
GROUP BY ventas.idEmp, ventas.idArt
ORDER BY ventas.idEmp, ventas.idArt
```

Con esa consulta no es necesario iterar sobre el resultado para calcular la suma.

Comment: Mil gracias efectivamente se podía resolver en la consulta